# Please explain this example of Rosen's book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

In Kenneth Rosen’s book example number 13 of Chapter 1.5 says,

There is a woman who has taken a flight on every airlines

In the example the solution is like this:

Let $P(w,f)$ $:$ $w$ has taken $f$

$Q(f,a)$ $:$ $f$ is a flight in $a$

And the answer is $∃w∀a∃f(P(w,f)∧Q(f,a))$

My question is why the answer is not $∃w∀a∃f(Q(f,a)\to P(w,f))$?

What is the difference between these two answers? Please explain.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  You'll get a better response if your post are easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that $Q(f,a) \rightarrow P(w,f)$ is a weaker statement than $Q(f,a) \land P(w,f)$; in particular, the first statement is true if $Q(f,a)$ is false regardless of whether $P(w,f)$ is true or not. This prevents it from matching up with the verbal statement.

For example, you could have a woman $w$ who has never taken a flight by some particular airline $a$, but since there exists a flight $f$ that is on some other airline, $Q(f,a) \rightarrow P(w,f)$ is true, so this woman could satisfy your logical statement but not Rosen's, and not the verbal statement.

In fact, as long as there are flights on at least two airlines, *every* woman would satisfy $\forall a \exists f (Q(f,a) \rightarrow P(w,f))$.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your explanation.